# django custom command

Tags: django

How i can get the current settings in a custom command and not the defaul settings?

Comment: You need to be more precise. What do you mean with current settings and what would be the difference to default settings? Do you mean a manage.py command with custom command?

Comment: I mean CACHE_BACKEND by example when i put memcache, and yes a custom command with manage.py

Comment: Please post example command line/code/output etc, since your question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the attribut `can_import_settings = True` in your class `Command`

Answer (score 0):

`from django.conf import settings`